# Aperture Doesn't Change on Nikon D7000 1.8D (Already set ring to 22)

Tags: lens, nikon-d7000, 50mm

I have a Nikon D7000 and I recently purchased a used 50mm f 1.8D for it. I am unable to get the aperture of the lens to change. It seems to stay stuck at completely open version of the lens (1.8f).

What I've done so far:

1. Set the aperture ring on the lens to 22
2. Locked the ring (using the orange button)
3. Change the aperture in the camera body with the dial

I get no errors, however, regardless of which aperture I set on the camera body, the lens stays wide open. For example, The photo I take on manual mode with 1.8f and 1/60 will look exactly same as 22f 1/60. I also don't see the lens blades closing.

If I dismount the lens the aperture ring correctly switches through all of the stops and the blades react properly. I have noticed that as soon as I put the lens on the camera body, the blades will completely open regardless of the F-Stop.

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. Any pointers will be greatly helpful!

Comment: Do you see/hear any aperture movement when you press the "Depth of Field Preview" button?   By default this is the button at the lower left of a D7000 (but it can be assigned other functions via the "Custom settings" menu).

Comment: @PeterM If I am on the lowest F-stop (1.8) I hear sound, if I am on another F-Stop I do hear a sound but I get "ERR" on the camera. I tried the lens that comes with the camera and it had the same behavior. Lowest F-Stop works okay, but anything else shows up as "ERR". Is this a settings issue?

Comment: According to [Nikon](https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/eu/BV_article?articleNo=000005282&configured=1&lang=en_GB) an "ERR" is "the cameras internal performance monitor has detected a problem".  That article mentions various reasons and possible fixes

Comment: Also when using the DoF preview button you should be able to see a change when looking at the front of the lens.

Comment: @PeterM I went through your links! It seems like I may have some sort of issue with the aperture lever. Nothing else in the article addressed the issue.  The lever however 
 doesn't look bent or broken. Maybe something internally is broken. I will have to get it look at by a repair shop. Thank so much for your help and support!

Comment: Hopefully the person you bought it from takes some responsibility if it is indeed broken

Comment: @PeterM I did find a solution for my situation as the lever itself didn't look broken. I posted it as an answer for now. Thanks a lot for your help in this process!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my situation in case it helps someone else.

I noticed that my aperture lever wasn't bent/broken like the Nikon website suggests. It felt more jammed. I took the following steps to unjam it:

1. Unmounted the lens.
2. **Gently** pressed the lever down along with the DoF Preview button while the camera was on. Taking a photo would probably have the same effect. All I was trying to do was to get the camera to unlock its hold on the lever.
3. Repeated these steps until the lever finally clicked in place.

Once it clicked into place, it operated as normal. It does get jammed now and then, but it's significantly easier to get it into place.

I would still recommend showing it to a repair shop if your situation is different from mine, or you feel unsure about doing these steps.

Comment: Great that you found a solution.  You can select your answer as the correct one (and this sort of thing is encouraged)